# Can I pass a reference to a variable into a function defined to take a normal variable?

Tags: php

I need to use the PHP function `strtolower($str)` to put a large string in all-lower-case.  Since the string is large, I would have liked if it could be taken as a reference and operated on.  For example (though this doesn't work):

I wanted to do:

```
$myLargeString = PopulateString();
strtolower(&$myLargeString);
```

instead of:

```
$myLargeString = PopulateString();
$myLargeString = strtolower($myLargeString);
```

is there any trick that would let me lower-case a string by reference to save some speed, or maybe another function I should be looking at?  I'm not particularly strong in PHP so I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: You could code a wrapper for strtolower that takes a string by reference, so you don't need to type it out each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot force a non-reference taking function to take a reference.  In fact, specifying that it's pass by reference at call time is now deprecated (http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

You could of course write your own implementation of strtolower().  As it would be in PHP and the strtolower implementation is in C, I'm not sure how much performance you could actually gain.  I suppose it would depend on how long the string is.

Comment: Writing a wrapper doesn't accomplish anything.  He wants to pass by reference to avoid the copy operation(s) incurred in passing the string in and returning it.  Adding an extra layer still leaves that process there.

Comment: Just tried to get a faster implementation of strtolower using a reference, and due to PHP's rather lack of ability to efficiently work on strings as an array of chars, I don't think it's possible.  I think you could make a lower memory usage strtolower(), but I think time wise, the C implemented one will always win.